# Phoenix: set router global context path

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Let's say in my `router.ex`, I have:

```
scope "/api" do
  get "/test", SomeController, :test
end
```

I now want to dynamically configure the root path for the whole application, so instead of it responding from `/api/test`, it would respond from `/context/api/test`.

Configuring the Endpoint `url` parameter seems to only change url generation.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adjusting the `path` configuration in your `url` config. If you set it like this, it "should" work:

```
config :my_app, MyAppWeb,
    url: [path: "/context"]
```

Comment: It does not. As mentioned, it seems to only change url generation.

Comment: I see. Could you specify please which part of the url you want to configure dynamically? Is it the `scope` of a route?